# Importing a Base64 encoded string

Tags: import, string-manipulation, character-encoding

I'm handling some paragraphs encoded with Base64 from CSV file format. The problem is that *Mathematica* can't decode it. I'm thinking to write my decode method by my own, but I ask it first.

By example:

I used `base64.b64encode` on python with the string:

```
s = '"Hola los felicito por su equipo de comunicadores. Me encanta verlos pues ustedes se salen de las   simplezas y superficialidades de los noticieros tradicionales.Un saludo desde Montreal- Canada.

Adelante! así como van en poco tiempo tendrán muchos mas seguidores que  la ""Gran prensa Colombiana"" la cual ha venido mintiendo por décadas.

"'
```

And outcome:

```
 b = 'IkhvbGEgbG9zIGZlbGljaXRvIHBvciBzdSBlcXVpcG8gZGUgY29tdW5pY2Fkb3Jlcy4gT\
WUgZW5jYW50YSB2ZXJsb3MgcHVlcyB1c3RlZGVzIHNlIHNhbGVuIGRlIGxhcyAgIHNpbXB\
sZXphcyB5IHN1cGVyZmljaWFsaWRhZGVzIGRlIGxvcyBub3RpY2llcm9zIHRyYWRpY2lvb\
mFsZXMuVW4gc2FsdWRvIGRlc2RlIE1vbnRyZWFsLSBDYW5hZGEuCgpBZGVsYW50ZSEgYXP\
DrSBjb21vIHZhbiBlbiBwb2NvIHRpZW1wbyB0ZW5kcsOhbiBtdWNob3MgbWFzIHNlZ3VpZ\
G9yZXMgcXVlICBsYSAiIkdyYW4gcHJlbnNhIENvbG9tYmlhbmEiIiBsYSBjdWFsIGhhIHZ\
lbmlkbyBtaW50aWVuZG8gcG9yIGTDqWNhZGFzLgoKIg=='
```

On *Mathematica*:

[image]

[image]

But if you use another base64 decoder like [decoderb64](http://www.base64decode.org), it can do the job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `"Base64"` is not a format but an encoding and you still need to tell Mathematica what format to import after decoding from Base64.  This is described [in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Base64.html).

Try this:

```
ImportString[s, {"Base64", "String"}]
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I don't figure out. I thought that "String" was implicit.

Comment: @d555 It could be anything, not just `String`.  Base64 is considered an encoding just like gzip (which is also supported).  Any file in any format can be encoded like this.