# Decoding GZIP encoded Body, BodyBytes (ByteArray) and BodyBytesArray from URLRead

Tags: conversion, web-access, character-encoding, binary, compression

When calling the [Stack Exchange API v2.2](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) using the new (Mma11) function [`URLRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLRead.html) we get a GZIP encoded Body in alternative formats: `"Body"`, `"BodyByteArray"` and `"BodyBytes"` depending on the options.

**How can we deal with each of these formats in order to decode the body in Mathematica?**

I am particularly intrigued with operating on [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray.html)

I know I could get the content using

```
Import[URLBuild[{"https://api.stackexchange.com", "2.2", 
   "info"}, {"site" -> "mathematica"}], "RawJSON"]
```

**My questions is about dealing explicitly with list of byte values as well as [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray.html) that are encoded. Hopefully without creating a temporary file, to then read it back.**

The code I'm using:

```
reply=URLRead[
 URLBuild[{"https://api.stackexchange.com", "2.2", "info"}, {"site" -> "mathematica"}]
 , {"Headers", "StatusCode", "StatusCodeDescription", "ContentType", 
  "BodyByteArray"}]
```

> ```
> <|"Headers" -> {
> "cache-control" -> "private"
> , "content-type" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8"
> , "content-encoding" -> "gzip"
> , "access-control-allow-origin" -> "*"
> , "access-control-allow-methods" -> "GET, POST"
> , "access-control-allow-credentials" -> "false"
> , "x-content-type-options" -> "nosniff"
> , "date" -> "Thu, 11 May 2017 10:55:51 GMT"
> , "content-length" -> "234"
> }
> , "StatusCode" -> 200
> , "StatusCodeDescription" -> "OK"
> , "ContentType" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8"
> , "BodyBytesArray" -> ByteArray[< 234 >]
> |>
> ```

By the way, strangely to me, `Import[URLRead[url], "RawJSON"]` doesn't work.

Comment: related: [45282](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45282/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"BodyBytes"`

- a list of bytes from http response. Does not mean much without encoding information

`"BodyByteArray"`

- afaict `"BodyBytes"` wrapped with `ByteArray`. (1.)

`"Body"`

- afaict, a String - `ToCharacterCode[#BodyBytes, encoding]`, where encoding is read from `charset` `content-type` header.

  That is a problem for us. First of all it ignores `content-encoding`. Additionally json does not need `charset` sub-header but without it it won't be recognized as utf8 (in case without gzip). Don't know if that is expected, probably deserves a spearate question.

So, the safe way (4.) is through bytes, e.g.:

```
URLRead[
    "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica"
  , "BodyBytes"
] // FromCharacterCode // ImportString[#, {"gzip", "RawJSON"}] & (*3.*)
```

> ```
> <|"items" -> {<|"new_active_users" -> 0, "total_users" -> 31928, 
>     "badges_per_minute" -> 0.03, "total_badges" -> 92485, 
>     "total_votes" -> 567164, "total_comments" -> 325306, 
>     "answers_per_minute" -> 0.02, "questions_per_minute" -> 0.01, 
>     "total_answers" -> 63637, "total_accepted" -> 23610, 
>     "total_unanswered" -> 4679, "total_questions" -> 43005, 
>     "api_revision" -> "2017.5.3.25597"|>}, "has_more" -> False, 
>  "quota_max" -> ..., "quota_remaining" -> ...|>
> ```

---

1. [What is the intended purpose of ByteArray](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1057042)
2. [Importing a Base64 encoded string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45282/5478)
3. [SO: Content-Encoding vs charset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5938007/4251542)
4. [Who is to blame: parsing UTF8 encoded JSON HTTPResponse fails](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154245/5478)