# GZIP decode fails when done manually

Tags: import

So I hit a minor snag in testing the users part of an API connection to SE. It seems Mathematica can't always decode the GZIP?

For instance this:

```
ImportString[
 FromCharacterCode[
  URLFetch["https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=mathematica.\
stackexchange.com&pagesize=100&page=5",
   "ContentData"
   ]
  ],
 "GZIP"
 ]
```

Throws:

> Import::infer: Cannot infer format of file InputStream[Name: String, Unique ID: 3].

On the other hand this:

```
Import["https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=mathematica.\
stackexchange.com&pagesize=100&page=5",
 "Text"
 ]
```

Seems to work totally fine.

How can I import the string the same way [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) does?

### Update:

Another wrinkle. If I import the bytes:

```
cdata = URLFetch[
   "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=mathematica.\
stackexchange.com&pagesize=100&page=5",
   "ContentData"
   ];
```

Then dump them to a file:

```
$setempfile = CreateFile[];
BinaryWrite[$setempfile, cdata];
```

I can import that file as bytes, but it's different from what I wrote:

```
In[196]:= cdata == Import[$setempfile, "Byte"]

Out[196]= False
```

And what is now read-in can be decoded properly:

```
In[197]:= StringTake[FromCharacterCode@Import[$setempfile, "Byte"], 50]

Out[197]= "{\"items\":[{\"badge_counts\":{\"bronze\":21,\"silver\":14"
```

So I'm doubly confused, as

```
Import[$setempfile, "gzip"]
```

Still fails.

Comment: You have to respect the header, partially :), that is to take content type and ignore encoding: `"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, encoding when enforced gives failures, don't know why. So, is this what you want? [145769](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145769/5478), `{"GZIP", "RawJSON"}`?

Comment: @Kuba seems to work. I'd assumed `{"GZIP", "RawJSON"}` was just reading in as `"GZIP"` then applying the `"RawJSON"`. I guess not. `{"GZIP", "Text"}` is what I actually need for various reasons, so I'll be going with that. Thanks.

Comment: By default it would be but manually you have to do that yourself. p.s. do you understand why content-type encoding does not matter?

Comment: @Kuba I do not. I did see that you were having troubles with an explicit  `CharacterEncoding` in your `FromCharacterCode`. I'm guessing that has to be applied at the time we decode the `"Text"` after converting the `"GZIP"`. E.g. `ImportString[FromCharacterCode@cdata,{"GZIP", "Text"}, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]`