# URLRead ignores content-encoding:gzip header

Tags: import, conversion, web-access, character-encoding

### Background

Taking an example from [Decoding GZIP encoded Body, BodyBytes (ByteArray) and BodyBytesArray from URLRead](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145769/5478):

```
URLRead[
 "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica", "Headers"
]
```

> ```
> { ... 
> , "content-type" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8"
> , "content-encoding" -> "gzip"
> , ...
> }
> ```

```
Import @ "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica"
```

returns string json which can be later put to `ImportString`.

### Problem

`URLRead` though throws a bunch of decoding errors suggesting it ignores `"gzip"` spec and goes directly to `charset` specified in `content-type`.

```
URLRead[
 "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica", "Body"
]
```

### Workaround

is already shown in linked topic:

```
URLRead[
    "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica"
  , "BodyBytes"
] // FromCharacterCode // ImportString[#, {"gzip", "RawJSON"}] &
```

### Question

Should that be the case? Is it a bug or am I missing the purpose of `URLRead` `Body`?

`URLFetch` behaves the same so I'm surprised it wasn't asked before.

```
URLFetch[
    "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica"
  , "Content"
]
```

### Related

[Who is to blame: parsing UTF8 encoded JSON HTTPResponse fails](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154245/who-is-to-blame-parsing-utf8-encoded-json-httpresponse-fails)

Comment: Note that `Import` actually does not need the `"content-encoding" -> "gzip"` header for recognizing `gzip` compressed data. You can check it with `file=URLDownload["https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica"];Import@file`. The created `file` is a binary `gzip`-compressed file and `Import` recognizes the compression method from the first few bytes of the file, the HTTP `"content-encoding"` header isn't necessary at all.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov good point, so no one cares about content-encoding :)

Comment: I would like to understand  this too  (+1). We knew that `Import` worked, from the quoted question.. BTW, *"As of Version 11, `URLFetch` has been superseded by `URLRead` and `URLExecute`."*

Comment: @rhermans and Alexey, now it works, does it mean it was a bug?

Comment: @Kuba I think it was a bug since ability to recognize `gzip` is of crucial importance for such function as `URLRead`. As I wrote above, I would expect it to recognize gzip even without the explicit `"content-encoding" -> "gzip"`. Probably the latter can be checked using the `file:` protocol.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov otoh URLFetch wasn't supporting it either and no one complained (out loud).

Comment: This just indicates that people still do not use this functionality for serious projects...

Comment: I just have checked: `URLRead["file://localhost/D%3A/Temp/test", "Body"]` (where `test` is a `gzip`-encoded file) returns compressed binary string, so it looks like `URLRead` needs explicit `"content-encoding" -> "gzip"` in order to function properly. BTW, I also found that in version 11.2.0 `URLDownload` saves already *uncompressed* data, while in version 11.1.1 it saved `gzip-`encoded data: `URLDownload["https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica"]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm fine with expecting the header to be there. I guess I will  prepare a test suite to run on different versions which will tell us what works and what does not. I don't care if something is a bug or not, I need to know up fron what will happen :) p.s. I don't know when I will find time for that but I guess it is worth doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of V11.2** *Content-Encoding* specification is respected by `URLRead` and e.g.

```
URLRead[
  "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=mathematica", "Body"
]
```

Works well.

For earlier versions one needs to use a workaround like one shown above.